# How do I show (G,*) is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a nonempty set and let * be an associative binary operation on G. Assume that for any elements a,b in G, we can find x,y in G such that a*x=b and y*a=b. (I need to use this assumption. I've been drawing a blank on this for a while now. I keep getting to a point where I have b*x=y*b and other little variations of this but I can't seem to show that b is the identity or that x=y and are thus the inverses of a. Once I show either of these properties the rest sort of falls into place)

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to choose some element $g_0 \in G$. This exists because $G$ is assumed to be non-empty.

We are looking for a neutral element $e$. This satisfies $g_0 e = g_0$. By assumption, there is some $e$ with this property. Okay, but what we really need is that $g e = g$ for all $g \in G$. By assumption we may write $g = h g_0$ for some $h$. Then, we have $g e = (h g_0) e = h(g_0 e)= h g_0 = g$.

Finally, we have to show that inverse elements $g^{-1}$ exist (i.e. $g g^{-1}=e$). But this follows directly from the assumption applied to $g$ and $e$.

Comment: Should we also want to show that this $e$ is also a left identity (using symmetry to show the existence of a left identity the same way we proved the existence of a right identity, and then multiply the two identities together to show they are equal), and then prove that any two-sided identity wrt an associative operation is unique?

Comment: It is a standard fact, which I didn't want to repeat here, that the group axioms may be weakened: Right neutral elements and right inverse elements suffice.

Comment: I have to prove this using the assumption "for any elements a,b in G, we can find x,y in G such that a*x=b and y*a=b". I had something similar to this and was told that it wasn't quite what they wanted.

Comment: I used exactly this assumption.